# Why does Enter in Sublime Text 3 not work properly with my Python Code

Tags: python, sublimetext3

So i want to learn some python specifically in sublime text but i have a problem.

```py
car = input("hello what car do you have?")

print = (car + ",wow i would burn that car to the ground")
```

when i type a random car manufacturer in terminal and press enter after i have started the "program" (by pressing command + b) it just skips to the next line.

i want it to print my next line of code which is the

```
 (car) ,wow i would burn that car to the ground
```

What am i doing wrong?

Is there something in my settings that i need to set up?

Note: i have run the same "program" in VSC (Visual Studio Code) and it works completely fine there.

Comment: Is `print = (...)` your **real** code? You assign to builtin function, not print...

Comment: Can you [fix the markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your post? It will help other's see the question more clearly.